# Как получить путь на две папки выше запущенного приложения?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Есть папка с exe файлом, которую, например, я получаю так -Directory.GetCurrentDirectory().
Как мне получить ссылку на две папки выше этого файла?

Comment: `+ "..\\..\\"`?

Comment: @arrowd Я получаю вот такую строку C:\Servers\Эксперименты\socialnetwork\SocialNetwork\bin\net47\win7-x86..\..\  а хочу- на 2 папки вверх. Они не преобразовались, как в cmd

Answer (score 5, accepted):

С помощью [Path.GetFullPath](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.path.getfullpath(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Path.GetFullPath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "\\..\\..\\");
```

Comment: Спасибо- вот- это то, что нужно. А я вожусь несколько часов, как это сделать....

Comment: Пробегитесь по остальным методам класса `Path`, там много полезного.